# Divergence formula

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I would like to obtain the following equation :
$\text{div}\left( \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{|\nabla u|^2 + \epsilon^2}} \right) 
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + |\nabla u|^2}} \left( g^{ij} - \frac{\nabla^i u \nabla^j u}{\epsilon^2 + |\nabla u|^2} \right) \nabla^2_{ij}u$
with $g$ being the metric on a manifold $M$.

I have tried using the different properties of the divergence but there is always a term missing...  Is this equation just basically saying that $div(A) = Tr (\nabla A)$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\text{div}\left( \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{|\nabla u|^2 + \epsilon^2}} \right) $ instead?

Comment: yes ! indeed, i changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you calculate that at the center of a normal coordinates, writing $X = \sum_i X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, then

$$\text{div} X = \sum_i \partial_i X^i.$$

So using $|\nabla u|^2 = \sum_j u_j^2$,

$$\begin{split}
\text{div} \left( \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{|\nabla u|^2 + \epsilon^2}}\right) &= \sum_i \left( \frac{ u_i}{\sqrt{|\nabla u|^2 + \epsilon^2}}\right)_i \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\nabla u|^2 + \epsilon^2}}\sum_i \left( u_{ii} - \sum_j \frac{u_{ij} u_i u_j}{|\nabla u|^2 + \epsilon^2}\right)
\end{split}$$

and that is what you want as (under normal coordinates)

$$\sum_i u_{ii} = \sum_{i,j} g^{ij} u_{ij},\ u_i = \nabla^i u,\ u_{ij}= \nabla^2_{ij} u.$$